# How to take the preceding Value based on condition in teradata sql

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I meet some issues when trying to get the preceding GRADE based on The BEGINING_DATE (when it change )

Here is my data :

| ID | GRADE | BEGINNING_DATE | ENDING_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 14/06/2021 | 14/06/2022 |
| 1 | 12 | 14/06/2021 | 14/06/2022 |
| 1 | 14 | 22/03/2022 | 22/03/2023 |
| 1 | 14 | 22/03/2022 | 22/03/2023 |
| 1 | 15 | 22/03/2023 | 22/03/2024 |
| 1 | 15 | 22/03/2023 | 22/03/2024 |
| 2 | 13 | 15/01/2022 | 15/01/2023 |
| 2 | 13 | 15/01/2022 | 15/01/2023 |
| 2 | 17 | 01/09/2023 | 01/09/2024 |
| 2 | 17 | 01/09/2023 | 01/09/2024 |

What i want is to get the preceding GRADE by ID when the BEGINING_DATE Change , here is what i want to get :

| ID | GRADE | BEGINNING_DATE | ENDING_DATE | LAG_GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 14/06/2021 | 14/06/2022 | ? |
| 1 | 12 | 14/06/2021 | 14/06/2022 | ? |
| 1 | 14 | 22/03/2022 | 22/03/2023 | 12 |
| 1 | 14 | 22/03/2022 | 22/03/2023 | 12 |
| 1 | 15 | 22/03/2023 | 22/03/2024 | 14 |
| 1 | 15 | 22/03/2023 | 22/03/2024 | 14 |
| 2 | 13 | 15/01/2022 | 15/01/2023 | ? |
| 2 | 13 | 15/01/2022 | 15/01/2023 | ? |
| 2 | 17 | 01/09/2023 | 01/09/2024 | 13 |
| 2 | 17 | 01/09/2023 | 01/09/2024 | 13 |

I try to use LAG Function but i can't get the result i want to

```
SELECT
A.*,
LAG(GRADE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID,BEGINING_DATE ORDER BY ENDING_DATE) AS LAG_GRADE
FROM 
DATA A
```

Can you help me please

Kind Regards

**SOLUTION :**

With the information of @Fred
I find the solution and the query is :

```
WITH DATA AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
   ID,
   GRADE,
   BEGINNING_DATE
FROM
    grade_data
),
LAG_DATA AS (
SELECT
  D.*,
  LAG(D.GRADE) OVER (PARTITION BY D.ID ORDER BY D.BEGINNING_DATE ) AS LAG_GRADE
FROM
DATA D
)
SELECT 
  GRADE.*,
  LD.LAG_GRADE
FROM
grade_data GRADE
LEFT JOIN LAG_DATA LD ON GRADE.ID=LD.ID AND GRADE.BEGINNING_DATE = LD.BEGINNING_DATE
```

Thanks you guys

Comment: Hi - 1) please don’t use images, add data as editable text, formatted as tables 2) please update your question with the SQL  you’ve managed to write so far

Comment: Teradata or MySQL?  Don't tag with multiple RDBMSs, the solutions may be completely different.

Comment: It's Teradata 
Thanks

Comment: @NickW , i don't know how to add data on stactoverflow but i added the query i've tried

Comment: This link describes how to format data as a table: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables

Comment: "*i don't know how to add data*" copy/paste is a start, then indent from the left as for code - even roughly formatted text is better then images **that I cannot access**. Please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: It appears your challenge is due to the duplicate rows in the table. You can use a subquery or CTE to get unique id, grade, beginning_date; apply lag or lead , then (outer) join the result back to the full table to fill in the lag_grade.

Comment: @NickW , added data as table 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in SQL server. I think the same logic could be implemented in Teradata SQL.

```
with prepared_data as
(
    select * , 
           lag(grade , 1) over(partition by id order by convert(date , beginning_date, 103)) as lagged_grade from
    (
        select * 
        from grade_data
        group by id , grade , beginning_date , ending_date
    ) as a
)
select a.* , b.lagged_grade
from grade_data as a inner join prepared_data as b 
on a.grade = b.grade and a.id = b.id and a.beginning_date = b.beginning_date and a.ending_date = b.ending_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , the query works but i use left join but in this case the left join and the inner join give the same result
Thanks a lot